# What is the meaning of the following syntax

Tags: angular, typescript

I am reading the official Angular tutorial, but I can't understand the meaning of the following code:

```
return (error: any): Observable<T> => {...};
```

The function apparently returns a function of which I can't understand the input. Is the input a variable named "error" of type "any" and the output an object of type Observable?

Comment: Where in the tutorial did you see that code? A bit of context would help.

Comment: In the http section, where it speaks about the error handling.

Comment: You know this is the web, and the web has URLs and links ;-)

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: It means that it returns a function whose `error` parameter is of type any, and the returned type of the function is `Observable<T>`. The definition of the actual function is after the `=>` (in the `{...}` part you mentionned)

Comment: Your guess about the meaning of the posted code is correct. Read the [documentation of TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the input a variable named "error" of type "any" and the output an object of type Observable?

Yes. The function takes an input parameter named "error" of type "any" and returns a value of type "Observable".